# Oracle custom sort using multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

```
id Status Closed_date target_date 
1  Open               03/20/2018
2  Closed 03/14/2018
3  closed 03/12/2018 
4  Open               04/20/2018
```

I need to sort it using Status, closed and target date. Something like first open items and then closed, if it is open sort ascending using target_date and closed then using closed_date.
I used this decode function to bring all open first and closed next, but do not know how to add date column to this condition.

```
ORDER BY decode(STATUS, 'Open', 1, 'Closed',2,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
order by status desc, target_date, closed_date
```

or

```
order by status desc, coalesce(target_date, closed_date)
```

This uses the fact that "open" and "closed" have a particular ordering, and that the date values are for one or the other.  A more explicit method would be:

```
order by (case when status = 'open' then 1 else 2 end),
         coalesce(target_date, closed_date)
```

Or, an even more explicit method:

```
order by (case when status = 'open' then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when status = 'open' then target_date end),
         (case when status = 'closed' then closed_date end)
```

I think one of the first two methods is clear enough in intent.